# Syntax error declaring and assigning to a global variable

Tags: python

I'm attempting to program a binary and decimal converter, but I'm getting hung up on a variable.

```
def conversion():
    global binaryOrDecimal = input('''Which way are you trying to convert?
    A: Binary to Decimal
    B: Decimal to Binary
    ''')

conversion()

if binaryOrDecimal == 'a' or 'A':
    print('test')
elif binaryOrDecimal == 'b' or 'B':
    print('test2')
else:
    print('invalid argument, please try again')
    conversion()
```

I'm getting the errors "End of statement expected" and "Statement expected, found Py:EQ", both on line 2.

Comment: `global binaryOrDecimal` needs to be a separate statement from `binaryOrDecimal = something`.

Comment: i just tested that and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a beginner myself, but I don't think you can assign a value to a variable and use the global keyword on the same line. So first you'd have to define your global variable:

```
global binaryOrDecimal
```

Then assign a value to it:

```
binaryOrDecimal = input('''Which way are you trying to convert?
A: Binary to Decimal
B: Decimal to Binary
''')
```

So overall, your function should be:

```
def conversion():
    global binaryOrDecimal 
    binaryOrDecimal = input('''Which way are you trying to convert?
    A: Binary to Decimal
    B: Decimal to Binary
    ''')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, couple things here.

One, that would not be how to define a global variable. Make sure that you assign a value to your global variable **after** you have defined it as global

```
global foo
foo = "a"
```

Second, in order to check if a variable is equal to two or more values, `binaryOrDecimal == 'b' or 'B':` will not work. You can use `in` for this which should check if an element occurs in an iterable.

```
if foo in ["bar1","bar2"]
```

But in your case, after you have taken the input, you can use `lower()` to lowercase the user input if it is capitalised. This way, you don't have to compare the input to 2 values.

So if we fix all these problems, you should end up with something like this.

```
def conversion():
    global binaryOrDecimal 
    binaryOrDecimal = input('''Which way are you trying to convert?
    A: Binary to Decimal
    B: Decimal to Binary
    ''').lower()

conversion()
if binaryOrDecimal == 'a':
    print('test')
elif binaryOrDecimal == 'b':
    print('test2')
else:
    print('invalid argument, please try again')
    conversion()
```

One last thing I would like to point out is, try not to use global variables. Instead, return a value. This way all your variables in your function are in a local scope, and will not be known to other functions.

```
def conversion():
    binaryOrDecimal = input('''Which way are you trying to convert?
    A: Binary to Decimal
    B: Decimal to Binary
    ''').lower()
    return binaryOrDecimal

binaryOrDecimal = conversion()
if binaryOrDecimal == 'a':
    print('test')
elif binaryOrDecimal == 'b':
    print('test2')
else:
    print('invalid argument, please try again')
    binaryOrDecimal = conversion()
```

Hopefully this helped :)